# How to set "ch_layout" in ffmpeg 6.1?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

In 6.1 Ffmpeg, it use "ch_layout" to replace the "channel_layout" and "number". The "ch_layout" is "AVChannelLayout *" type. This type is defined in channel_layout.h, some kind of "ch_layout" is defined in this file too.
If I want to use the "av_dict_set_int()" set the "ch_layout" to "AV_CHANNEL_LAYOUT_STEREO", what should I fill to the "value"?

```
/**
 * Macro to define native channel layouts
 *
 * @note This doesn't use designated initializers for compatibility with C++ 17 and older.
 */
#define AV_CHANNEL_LAYOUT_MASK(nb, m) \
    { /* .order */ AV_CHANNEL_ORDER_NATIVE, \
      /* .nb_channels */  (nb), \
      /* .u.mask */ { m }, \
      /* .opaque */ NULL }

/**
 * @name Common pre-defined channel layouts
 * @{
 */
#define AV_CHANNEL_LAYOUT_MONO              AV_CHANNEL_LAYOUT_MASK(1,  AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO)
#define AV_CHANNEL_LAYOUT_STEREO            AV_CHANNEL_LAYOUT_MASK(2,  AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO)
#define AV_CHANNEL_LAYOUT_2POINT1           AV_CHANNEL_LAYOUT_MASK(3,  AV_CH_LAYOUT_2POINT1)
#define AV_CHANNEL_LAYOUT_2_1               AV_CHANNEL_LAYOUT_MASK(3,  AV_CH_LAYOUT_2_1)
```

```
/**
 * Convenience wrapper for av_dict_set() that converts the value to a string
 * and stores it.
 *
 * Note: If ::AV_DICT_DONT_STRDUP_KEY is set, key will be freed on error.
 */
int av_dict_set_int(AVDictionary **pm, const char *key, int64_t value, int flags);
```